# Remove function from mutable set

Tags: scala

I want to store an object's method in a mutable Set. I can add the method without a problem, but cannot remove it:

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable.Set
import scala.collection.mutable.Set

scala> class c {
     | def f(value: Double) {
     | println(value)
     | }
     | }
defined class c

scala> val o = new c
o: c = c@4b08e64d

scala> val s = Set.empty[Function1[Double, Unit]]
s: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Double => Unit] = Set()

scala> s add o.f
res0: Boolean = true

scala> s.size
res1: Int = 1

scala> s remove o.f
res2: Boolean = false

scala> s.size
res3: Int = 1
```

If I create a set for holding an object of type c, everything works as expected.

```
scala> val s2 = Set.empty[c]
s2: scala.collection.mutable.Set[c] = Set()

scala> s2 add o
res4: Boolean = true

scala> s2.size
res5: Int = 1

scala> s2 remove o
res6: Boolean = true

scala> s2.size
res7: Int = 0
```

Is what I want to do possible?

Comment: Your wish to "… store an object's method in …" is flatly impossible. Methods are not first-class entities and cannot be treated as values. But their 1st-class counterpart, functions, can. Nonetheless, the down-side is that they don't have meaningful identities and are not readily equality-testable. Thus they dont' work well for the purpose of storage in and retrieval from a collection.

Answer (score 1):

`o.f` is analogous to a function pointer but is really not.

```
scala> o.f _
res6: Double => Unit = <function1>

scala> res6.##
res7: Int = 1849765122

scala> o.f _
res8: Double => Unit = <function1>

scala> res8.##
res9: Int = 509798553
```

Is it possible?  Mais oui! C'est possible!

```
scala> import reflect.runtime.universe._
import reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> import reflect.runtime.currentMirror
import reflect.runtime.currentMirror

scala> currentMirror reflect o
res12: reflect.runtime.universe.InstanceMirror = instance mirror for c@5a8c6475

scala> typeOf[c]
res13: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = c

scala> .declaration(TermName("f"))
res14: reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol = method f

scala> res12 reflectMethod res14.asMethod
res15: reflect.runtime.universe.MethodMirror = method mirror for c.f(value: scala.Double): scala.Unit (bound to c@5a8c6475)

scala> val ms = Set.empty[MethodMirror]
ms: scala.collection.mutable.Set[reflect.runtime.universe.MethodMirror] = Set()

scala> .add(res15)
res16: Boolean = true

scala> ms.remove(res15)
res17: Boolean = true
```

Edit:

Ignore my French, that is mirror-specific anyway, so it is not an improvement.

In other words, use java reflection.

```
scala> classOf[c].getMethod("f", classOf[Double])
res23: java.lang.reflect.Method = public void c.f(double)

scala> res23.##
res24: Int = 521628901

scala> classOf[c].getMethod("f", classOf[Double])
res25: java.lang.reflect.Method = public void c.f(double)

scala> res25.##
res26: Int = 521628901
```

Comment: in other words, `val x = o.f _; s add x; s remove x;`.

Comment: @som-snytt In your third block of code, you are not accessing o's instance method, you are accessing c's method. Is that correct?

Comment: @bwroga yes, it's the same as res14, you can create a func val to invoke it (currying the instance, as it were) but that's not useful for comparison.  I could imagine a case class that pairs a method and instance.